# android emulator not launching

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to android and I have run my codes on emulator for last few days. But today morning android emulator is not launching the android console showing message like:

```
"Android Launch!"
"adb is running normally."
"Performing com.HelloAndroid.HelloAndroid activity launch"
"Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Launch' is not available. Launching new emulator."

"Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Launch".
```

I think after this console should show messages like `Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...` etc etc. But in my case android console show no more messages and android emulator is not loading. Anybody know the reason. I am working on fedora 13 with eclipse helios version 3.6.2

Thanks

Comment: what is the android version you are using for your app and emulator?

Comment: my problem solve from this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607295/trouble-running-the-emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this rightclick on ur project select Run As>Run Configurations switch to "Target" tab select radio button to "manual" instead "automatic" & set the emulator you want apply it & run

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two ways :

1. Restart emulator and eclipse.
2. Make new emulator and try to launch this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is another instance of adb running. Go to the task manager (on windows only) and end the process