# trouble running the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, adt

If I run my application when there is allready an emulator running, the applications isn't run on the existing AVD, but a new one is started.

```
[2011-12-22 18:03:15 - Report_v6_2] ------------------------------
[2011-12-22 18:03:15 - Report_v6_2] Android Launch!
[2011-12-22 18:03:15 - Report_v6_2] adb is running normally.
[2011-12-22 18:03:15 - Report_v6_2] Performing mast.avalons.ReportActivity activity launch
[2011-12-22 18:03:15 - Report_v6_2] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Acer' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-12-22 18:03:15 - Report_v6_2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Acer'
[2011-12-22 18:03:28 - Report_v6_2] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-12-22 18:03:28 - Report_v6_2] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched ...
[2011-12-22 18:04:46 - Report_v6_2] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'mast.avalons.ReportActivity activity launch'!
[2011-12-22 18:20:16 - Report_v6_2] ------------------------------
[2011-12-22 18:20:16 - Report_v6_2] Android Launch!
[2011-12-22 18:20:16 - Report_v6_2] adb is running normally.
```

I use Windows 7, Eclipse Indigo, last versions adt, adb,sdk

Comment: I also have this problem. how it is solved?

Comment: Perhaps you know, why `Preferred AVD 'Acer' is not available.`?

Comment: Which OS, which dev environment, how you launch application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q: Has this *ever* worked on your Windows 7 PC?

Suggestion:

> http://androidforums.com/application-development/5398-android-help-emulator-5554-disconnected.html
>
> - solution : before message like "emulator-5554 disconnected!
>     Cancelling " go to Eclipse IDE-->window--> Show Views --> device-->
>     view menu --> reset adb

Answer (score 3):

This is caused when your project properties are not setup to run manually and for whatever reason (SDK or Target version) the emulator opens in a new instance.

To Solve:
Right Click your Project --> Run As --> Run Configurations

Then, make sure the Project in question is the one selected on the left and the Name is on the top.

You will then see 'Target' at the top:
[image]

Choosing **Manual** should allow you to choose the running emulator. If not, make sure your project SDK is set with an SDK version you have installed or a range that is compliant:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try this! Possibly this could answer your query. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049798/1051682
Also, if you can give it a try using Android x86, may resolve your issues.

Hmm...Looking at the first problem statement where "trying to open new app (in same emulator) when one is already running in emulator..." above mentioned link seemed to be relative thinking it could be similar issue. And if that problem exist, trying Android x86 comes next. Anyways. "Run as" pops up "Android Device Chooser" wherein you can select the already running emulator/device. I am unable to paste image, being new, but hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck at the first hurdle - The Hello World app. 
I kept seeing an `emulator-5554` appear which my debugger was connecting to; after a bit of digging in the package names of the emulator from within `DDMS`, I noticed 'bluestacks'. I had Bluestacks emulator installed. On Mac i went to `Library>Bluestacks` Player and uninstalled - solved the problem.