# android Avd(emulator) is not displaying after launching

Tags: android, android-emulator

While running an Android project, avd(emulator) is not launching and also not displaying any error.

I got below message on console:

STA is my project name and n_avd is my avd name

```
[2012-12-27 17:12:19 - STA] Android Launch!
[2012-12-27 17:12:19 - STA] adb is running normally.
[2012-12-27 17:12:19 - STA] Performing com.nil.android.sta.launch.SplashScreen activity launch
[2012-12-27 17:12:19 - STA] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'n_AVD'
[2012-12-27 17:12:19 - STA] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'n_AVD'
```

Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799997/android-emulator-not-launching) may help you. check once

Comment: hi check your sdk version and emulator version

Answer (score 1):

I have better luck if I first start the emulator, then once it is running (and connected) I then deploy my app.

Starting the AVD and deploying to it in a single step doesn't usually work for me.